# oauth based authentication query

Tags: security, cookies, oauth-2.0

I have an existing web application hosted using http.
For certain sections I force users to login with Google ( OAuth ) and harvest their email ids.
I then set a cookie for 6 months and set its contents as a encoded string which consists of two variables - x & z

```
String x = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
String z = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
String cookieValue = URLEncoder.encode("z="+z+"&x="+x, "UTF-8");
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("someDomain",cookieValue);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);   
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setMaxAge(6 Months);`
```

These same values 'x' and 'z' are then stored against the user's record in the database and on every access by the user - these values are changed in cookie and also in database.

Do you see any security issues in this approach ?

Comment: Start by using https.

Answer (score 0):

The two random values concatenated don't give you any more entropy/randomness than a single random value `y` where `length(y) = length(x) + length(z)`.

A system like this must only be used over secure HTTPs but even then: using a cookie that lives for 6 months is not a really secure approach. It would be better to check on a regular basis that the account of the associated user still exists at Google e.g. by using Google's refresh token.

A typical web application that leverage Google+ Signin would just rely on Google to maintain SSO session state without overriding that for their application. Thus the application would use session cookies only valid for the duration of the browser session and make the user go through Google Signin again for new sessions leaving it up to Google to determine whether an SSO session still exists.

Outsourcing the SSO session to Google avoids the need for storing long-lived session cookies in the application and increases the overall security at the cost of an increased number of explicit logins (which would happen anyway for the other applications connected to Google+ Signin).